# LTspice stacks data points on the same vector when I do linear parameter sweep

Tags: power, transformer, ltspice

I am trying to export the voltage of a transformer for different mutual coupling values. However, when I do a linear increase of mutual coupling it seems that LTspice will stack the parameters in one vector. Thus, I don't know what voltage corresponds to mutual coupling.

On top of that, LTspice does not simulate with a fixed number of data points so I just can't break the vector to equally smaller vectors.

Selecting the "list" as the nature of sweep will show me the data points corresponding to the mutual coupling. BUT list works only for 3 different parameters which is not helpful to interpret my results. Is there any way to increase the number of parameters for a list sweep?

Let me know your suggestions or alternative to tackle this problem.

Comment: Please post an example of your code

Comment: Have you considered using .MEAS and then plotting the results? Once done, you can then go to the view spice error log and right click to get an option to plot the results for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LTspice is quite capable and the .MEAS card is very important and, for some things, the only way to achieve them. It's not completely clear to me what you seek, but I can set up a simplified schematic to illustrate what I imagine may be closely related to your question. So I'll take a guess and hopefully it will stimulate your ability to get an answer to your question.

I'll set up a simple 1:1 transformer, which will require that I use a mutual inductance card (.K). Although not shown on the schematic, I added a parasitic series resistance, to both primary and secondary, of \$50\:\text{m}\Omega\$. The rest is shown on the schematic below:

[image]

You can see both the schematic I used as well as the resulting current waveform in \$R_1\$.

The next step I take is to select the View\SPICE Error Log menu selection, which pops up a nice dialog showing the results of the measurements I made. (See the .MEAS card on the schematic for details.) Then I right-clicked on that dialog to get what you see here below:

[image]

The above shows the highlighted selection I want to make. So I selected that and received the following chart:

[image]

That's an approach to what I think you are asking about. But as I said I'm not entirely sure about that. But hopefully I managed to guess right.